# Get git repository into a folder including description file & branches directory

Tags: git

this is my first time using git, and I am attempting to download absolutely everything from my gitlab repository, but I only seem to be able to download the master branch. I want to get everything in the root directory, including /description and /branches .. absolutely everything.

branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs

This is what I have so far ..please help

```
git config --global user.name "myUsername"
git config --global user.email "myEmail"

git config --global credential.helper cache
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'

rm -rf ~/gitlab
cd ~
mkdir gitlab
cd gitlab

git config remote.origin.url https://username:password@gitlab.com/username/repo.git
```

Comment: Hi. I have added a full answer with few options for you to follow. Feel free to ask anything if it's not clear to you.

Comment: You're not downloading only the master branch, you're downloading everything when you clone. You haven't added a local label (branch) for each remote branch, but all the commits are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is my first time using git, and I am attempting to download absolutely everything from my gitlab repository, but I only seem to be able to download the master branch

When you `clone` repository you get the default branch checked out.

All your branches and tags are also checked out as well.

```
mkdir gitlab
cd gitlab

# init empty repository
git init

# add the remote url to the repo
git remote add origin <url>

# fetch all the data from the remote
git fetch --all --prune
```

---

#### Option 2:

```
# simply clone all the data from the remote repository
git clone <url> <desired folder name>
```

---

#### How to update my repo with all the remote data?

```
# fetch all the data from the server including tags, branches and remove
# any local data which was removed on the server
git fetch --all --prune
```

This will update your repository with all the branches tags and more.

---

#### How to list all my branches?

```
# List all the branches - locally and remotely
# -a = all branches, both locally and remotly
git branch -a
```

---

#### how to clone a specific branch?

```
git clone -b <branch_name> <url>
```

---

#### How to change GitHub default branch?

https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch/

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is `git clone https://username:password@gitlab.com/username/repo.git`.

Comment: this just gets the master branch :(

Comment: `git clone` actually gets all branches; run `git branch -a` to see all of them. For any branch called `remotes/XXX/YYY`, do `git checkout YYY` to make a local branch that is associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to the folder you want to store your project in using "cd" in the console. Example: `"cd Desktop/Xcode/project"`
2. `"git init"`
3. `"git remote add origin git@github.com:ACCOUNT/PROJECT.git"` with ACCOUNT being your Github account name and PROJECT being the name of the repository on Github.
4. `"git pull origin master"`
5. Hit Esc once the VIM editor opens
6. `"ZZ"` Make sure they're capital Z's.

Should work.

Comment: Okay, trying this now

Comment: Got to figure out SSH key thing

Comment: this just gets the master branch also :(

Answer (score 0):

**Don't worry; Git working as intended and is copying everything you need.**

The reason you can only download the master branch is that this is how git is supposed to work.  The extra directories you are referring to are "private" to a repository.  In this case, the branches you're talking about are the server's configuration, hooks, etc.

Git essentially stores all its data in the filesystem, and what you are looking at is a ["bare" repository](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/).

When you clone this bare repository, git sets up similar directories, but they're in your .git directory.  They don't always copy what is on your server (hooks for example do *NOT* get automatically set up).

Also, since you mentioned the master branch, git will automatically place you on the master branch.  If you've got other branches on the server, you will be able to see them via `git branch -r`.  To switch to a branch, just type `git checkout <branchname>`.  Git will associate your local branch with that of the branch on the server with the same name.